# @Async suddenly stopped working in Spring boot app after a few days away from workspace with no apparent changes?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-tool-suite

I have a Springboot restful webapp  and I'm using @Async to run a method to do processing on some data. A request comes a Controller.java class.and I return a response in main thread like "Request has been received.." while a new thread gets spun up and does the processing.

It was working fine but I come back to it today after the weekend and it no longer creates new threads. I confirmed async pieces of code have not been modified.  I have not seen any scheduled maintenance for my remote desktop, checked my windows log to see if there were any events that might cause my workspace to be out of sync or something but haven't found anything.

I've looked all over SO and only found problem/solutions when things are missing like annotations or no Async Configurations..etc all of which i can confirm i have implemented, as I said it was working previously.

Has anyone ever encountered this behavior where an @Async annotation suddenly stops working?

Modified code snippet below.

```
//a java file an impl class
@Repository
public class InterfaceImpl implements Interface {

     @Autoriwed
     @Qualifier("Qualifier")
     Interface service;


     //iforget how its implemented at work something like this to illustrate
     @PostMapping(application/process)
     public ResponseEntity processdata(@RequestBody String lotsofdata) {
         ResponseEntity entity = new ResponseEntity();

         service.asyncMethod();

         return Status.OK.entity("Request received. Processing.").build();
   }      
}

//a java file an impl class
@Service(value = "Qualifier")
public class InterfaceImpl implements Interface {

     @Override
     @Async("processExecutor")
     public void asyncMethod(){
         # do some heavy stuff
     }        
}

               
//a java file--an interface for above class
public interface Interface {
     void asyncMethod();

} 

//a pretty boilerplate asyncconfig java file                             
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    //to catch exceptions in thread
    @Autowired
    CustomAsyncExceptionHandler asyncExceptionHandler;

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        return asyncExceptionHandler;
    }

    @Bean(name="processExecutor")
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3);    
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(3); 
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);      
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Is there something in Springtool Suite or with Tomcat that maybe needs a refresh or something? I'm pulling my hair out because of it.  I haven't removed any dependencies out of my pom.  As i said it was working previously and I'm kind of looking for things that others might have seen along similar lines of behavior and maybe what they looked at to diagnose a cause.  I have not seen any bugs reported on this in my searches but could it be a potential bug?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of anything related to Spring Tools that might cause this change in behavior or that needs updating. Sorry.

Comment: What happens if you run your Spring Boot app from the command line? Same (wrong) behavior? That is usually a good indicator about whether the IDE is involved in this behavior or not.

Comment: Thanks Martin Lippert I will try this tomorrow. I do see in my logs in sts that "some beans are not eligible for proxies" or something like that. I know async uses proxies of the beans to run. Not sure if that's the cause or not but even if it was, the curious thing is what caused this proxy! –

Comment: @chamburger were you able to solve this? If yes please help me I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @VikasSingh nope i actually created a new workspace, i could not find why it all of a sudden stpped working.  What i did was I deleted the async stuff and then gradually readded it in a new workspace

Comment: @VikasSingh where you able to pinpoint the root of this issue?